# Share folders Docker

Tags: apache, docker

I'm used to develop on vagrant but docker looks faster so I just tried it. This seems really good but I need to share the folders between my host and docker to easily update my code without recompiling docker.

I tried to add:

```
VOLUME /Users/ajouve/dev/test/test:/var/www/test
```

or

```
VOLUME /Users/ajouve/dev/test/test:/var/www/test:rw
```

in my dockerfile but the folders are nos sync

This is my complete dockfile

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

MAINTAINER ajouve version: 0.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir /var/www/test
VOLUME /Users/ajouve/dev/test/test:/var/www/test:rw

COPY test.conf /etc/apache2/sites-availables/

RUN ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-availables/test.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.conf 

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

this is the test.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.local

    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    <Directory /var/www/test>
        # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/test-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/test-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have an empty folder when I'm trying to access to the server via a browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the folder when you start your docker instance

with `-v /src/dockerShared/:/usr/local/src`

have a Look [here](http://blog.zenika.com/index.php?post/2014/10/07/Setting-up-a-development-environment-using-Docker-and-Vagrant) for a example

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that the `VOLUME` instruction in a Dockerfile cannot have `:`. It is meant to declare which part of the container filesystem would never be written to the container layered filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Your host folder have to be owned by the same uid:gid of the folder inside the container.